# What is the file extension for the Hack programming language?

Tags: hacklang

Does anyone know the file extension for Hack? I've looked pretty much everywhere, and can't seem to find it. Thanks

Comment: Did you do a google search?

Comment: @SamOrozco I did, still didn't find an answer

Comment: The accepted answer was the first result on google. William Lee..

Comment: @SamOrozco Do realise that the accepted answer says "I think". The Wikipedia article did not explicitly say that the extension is `.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vim plugin for hack uses the extension .hh for hack files

[vim-hack github](https://github.com/hhvm/vim-hack/blob/master/ftdetect/hack.vim)

Answer (score 2):

HHVM supports 4 file extension for hack [`.hh`, `.hck` and `.hack`.](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/3df035714e281ea56d2d99592757277fb8e44401/hphp/hack/src/utils/findUtils.ml#L16)

starting from hhvm 4, hack now uses the `.hack` file extension by default which [doesn't require the `<?hh` opening tag](https://hhvm.com/blog/2019/02/11/hhvm-4.0.0.html).

> We now recommend using the .hack file extension if your editor/IDE support it;
>   files with this extension are always strict, and do not require or allow a `<?hh` header line.
>
> For example, this is a complete .hack file:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env hhvm
> <<__EntryPoint>>
> function main(): noreturn {
>  print("Hello, world!\n");
>  exit(0);
> }
> ```

`example.hh` / `example.hck` / `example.php` :

```
<?hh // strict

<<__EntryPoint>>
async function main(): Awaitable<void> {
  print 'hello, world';
}
```

`example.hack` :

```
<<__EntryPoint>>
async function main(): Awaitable<void> {
  print 'hello, world';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read something about it in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_(programming_language)

and I think that you can use .php because it should be similar to php.
Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Hack was created by Facebook as a dialect of PHP. They use .php files for their projects write in hack.

** -- UPDATE 2020 -- **
Today on their hite Hack recomendo use .hack as extension https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/getting-started/tools

vscode Hack languae extension continue to use .php as extension on their examples https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranayagarwal.vscode-hack